# How to iterate twice through Iterable in Reduce function in Hadoop

Tags: java, mapreduce

I have a situation where I need to iterate twice on a `Iterable` input of Reduce function in **Hadoop** Map reduce job.

Now, I have come to know that I cant iterate twice and the work around is that I can store data in an intermediate collection such as `LinkedList`.

The problem now is, when I try to write values into `LinkedList`, instead of writing current values, it just copies over the values through the whole list.

For example: `LinkedList`, position : 1 :a ( works fine up to this point)
Now when I write second value ( say b) it also replaces first value to b.

> So instead of
>     List, pos: 1 : a
>     List, pos :2 : b

> It writes
>   List, pos : 1 :b
>   List, pos : 2 :b

Anyone knows why is that happening? And any solution or workaround for this? ( The execution does not throw any error)

Comment: Have you tried making copies of the objects and putting the copies into the `LinkedList`?

Comment: Yes...I have tried it in multiple ways...one through making copy of Iterable itself...another through trying different collections such as a Hashmap & Arraylist. None of them worked.

Comment: I found the solution at last...inside the first iteration...assign current iterated value like this::
cache.add(new Datatype_of_iterator(current_value.get()))
and then iterate through cache again. (cache can be any collection such as LinkedList or Arraylist)